# Проблема с установкой размеров по макетам на bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что размеры на макете и на сайте не сходятся, хотя виделяю сколько же места, размер экрана подходит под все 12 колонок, делаю размер текста такой-же как в макете, но всеравно очень часто может что-то не влезать. Вот например скришнот:

[image: Скриншот с фотошопа]

выделил так же 3 колонки, размер тексту 24pt, но у меня уже всё съехало:

[image: Скриншот моей работы]

Это я туплю или и правда иногда размеры могут не совпадать? Ещё часто с высотой не совпадает. Делаю точно такие-же маргины, но не влезает все в блок.

Comment: У вас наглядно видно, что в макете надпись "print media design" выходит за пределы колонки - она там не по размеру, и естественно когда вы вставляете этот текст в колонку такого размера, он делает перенос

Comment: как тогда быть? делать шрифт чуть меньше?

Comment: если требование пиксельперфект, то можно сделать для заголовка внутренний отрицательный маргин в сторону отступа, но лучше обговорить с дизайнером, чтобы он понимал, что таким образом выходит за рамки бутстраповской сетки